ngrok - two sub-domains on the same agent
I am on a paid plan of ngrok
I have a static domain allocated, call it abcd.ngrok.app
I have an agent running on my computer where I have two http app servers:

port 3001 - an admin app
port 5050 - an api for webhook calls

I want ngrok to allow me to map:
abcd.ngrok.app/admin --> localhost:3001
abcd.ngrok.app/api --> localhost:5050
I defined an Edge  mapped to this domain, with two routes.
However I am not able to set what is the desired backend server to use. It doesnt allow me to change that.
I have this yaml configiration on the agent side:
version: 3
agent:
authtoken: AUTH_TOKEN
tunnels:
my_tunnel_name:
labels:
- edge=edghts_xxxxx
addr: 3001
tunnel2:
labels:
- edge=edghts_xxxxx
addr: 5050
What am i doing wrong??????
I configured as a above, but nothing worked
